# Enzyme restore getEelemenById before each test

Tags: javascript, sinon, enzyme, sinon-chai, chai-enzyme

I stub `getElementById` in `beforeEach`, and want to restore it before another test and stub again with anothter returns value. Because now I recieve error
`TypeError: Attempted to wrap getElementById which is already wrapped`

```
 let loginUrl = 'loginUrl'
    const url = '/app/auth'
    const textContent = `{&quot;${loginUrl}&quot;:&quot;${url}&quot;}`
    let htmlDecode

    describe('identityServer', () => {

        beforeEach(() => {
            htmlDecode = sinon.stub().returns(textContent)
            sinon.stub(document, 'getElementById').returns({textContent})
            sinon.stub(htmlEncoder, 'Encoder').returns({htmlDecode: () => htmlDecode})

            identityServerModel()
        })

        it('should return correct model for IdentityServer', () => {
            window.identityServer.getModel().should.deep.equal({[loginUrl]: url})
        })
    })

    describe('identityServer', () => {

        beforeEach(() => {
            htmlDecode = sinon.stub().returns(textContent)
            sinon.stub(document, 'getElementById').returns({innerHTML: textContent})
            sinon.stub(htmlEncoder, 'Encoder').returns({htmlDecode: () => htmlDecode})

            identityServerModel()
        })
        it('should return correct model using serialization HTML from innerHTML property when textContent is undefined', () => {
            window.identityServer.getModel().should.deep.equal({[loginUrl]: url})
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add:

```
afterEach(() => {
    document.getElementById.restore();
})
```

into every `describe(...)`.